# Amazon EC2 instance's var/www folder mounted on ubuntu machine freezes after some time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mount, gedit

I am using virtual box to run Ubuntu on my machine. I mount the /var/www folder of my amazon instance to my ubuntu machine using sshfs. But lately, I have been always experiencing that after ten minutes or so, the mounted drive freezes and I am unable to touch the files anymore. Even gEdit freezes and I have to always turn the machine off and put it on again to mount the drive again and work on the files. This way, my development is becoming really slow and boring.

Please let me know if there is a way I can solve this freezing or if there is a different way( other than mounting ) of accessing the files of amazon instance live and edit them and save them then and there.

Thanking you all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself by mounting the ec2 drive on windows using WinSSHFS and so I didnt need to  be dependent on my virtual machine to access the files of my ec2 instance. Win SSHFS asks for amazon private key file. Make sure to open the file in notepad and split the lines into small lines, ie; one line should not have more than 64 chars. Only after doing this, Win SSHFS accepted the private key file.
Make sure that the details in WinSSHFS are saved by clicking on the save button before mounting is attempted. Normal username is ec2-user. Enter the drive name you want to mount and mount to any logical drive.